# Cant click a Bootstrap dropdown-menu via Java/Selenium

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, selenium

I am newbie at Selenium and am trying to test a bootstrap menu with it.

I am trying to click on a specific row in a dropdown-menu but get 'no such element'.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class Foo  {


    @Test
    public void tryToClick() throws Exception {
        final WebDriver driver =
                new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("file:///tmp/foo.html");

        WebElement dropdownToggle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('dropdown-toggle-id')"));

        Actions cursor = new Actions(driver);
        cursor.moveToElement(dropdownToggle);
        cursor.click();
        cursor.perform();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement weh = driver.findElement(By.id("id('id-b')"));
        // Now I get ...
        // org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"id('id-b')"}
        // Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"id('id-b')"}

        Actions cursor2 = new Actions(driver);    
        cursor2.moveToElement(weh);
        cursor2.click();

    }

}
```

A example page to show problem is here :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Bootstrap 3 Skeleton - jsFiddle demo</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style type='text/css'>
    @import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
  </style>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
});//]]>  
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown-toggle-id" data-toggle="dropdown">
            My Menu<b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu-id">
        <li><a href="#" id="id-a"> <span class="fa fa-lg fa-user"></span>AA</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="id-b"><span class="fa fa-lg fa-cog"></span>BB</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</body>
</html>
```

With JQuery I can do this which seems okay:
`$("#dropdown-toggle-id").click()` and
`$("#id-b").click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`WebElement weh = driver.findElement(By.id("id('id-b')"));`

to

`WebElement weh = driver.findElement(By.id("id-b"));`

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Select(WebElement element);` method

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("dropdown-toggle-id"))).selectByIndex(1);
```

Or

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("dropdown-toggle-id"))).selectByVisibleText("BB");
```

Comment: My issue fixed now; but for the record ... I cant use SelectElement since  id("dropdown-toggle-id") is not a SELECT tag.... hence a UnexpectedTagNameException.

Comment: SelectElement is a C# reference, apologies about that but this will work: `new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("dropdown-toggle-id"))).selectByVisibleText("BB");`